# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Успешно закончил проект на  ларавел и начал другой (обычный сайт без баз данных). После окончания второго вернулся к первому. Но не могу запустить базу данных `php artisan migrate`- получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

локально ничего не менял.
В **.env** всё как и раньше. 
Единственно что изменил, так это **DocumentRoot** в *xampp* на путь к папке **public** этого проэкта.

Погуглив, я получаю ответы типа:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan migrate:install
 проверить .env 
 mysql -u db_user -p db_name
```

конечно же это всё не подходит. Больше всего меня в ступор ставит: почему возникла эта ошибка после смены проэкта ибо ранее без каких-либо изменений всё отлично работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос решился странным образом:

1. создал базу database (внезапно `localhost/phpmyadmin` загрузился, раньше выдавал ошибку server not responding)
2. `php artisan config:cache`
3. `composer update`
4. `php artisan migrate`